# Kivy - Setting event actions using dynamic classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm currently trying to trigger events of some widgets nested in dynamic classes. To be more specific. This is an example kv file:

```
    <UserSelectionInput@BoxLayout>:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: None, 1
        spacing: 4

        lb_text: ''
        lb_id: 'user_selection_label'
        sp_values: '', ''
        sp_id: 'user_selection_spinner'

        Label:
            id: root.lb_id
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            text: root.lb_text
        Spinner:
            id: root.sp_id
            text: 'Select'
            values: root.sp_values

    <InnerBox@AnchorLayout>:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint: None, 1
            width: 2 * root.width / 3
            spacing: 1

            UserSelectionInput:
                width: root.width / 3
                sp_values: 'A', 'B', 'C'
                lb_text: 'Type'
                lb_id: 'label_1'
                sp_id: 'spinner_1'
            UserSelectionInput:
                width: root.width / 3
                sp_values: 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'
                lb_text: 'Version'
                lb_id: 'label_2'
                sp_id: 'spinner_2'

    <MainContent>:
        rows: 3

        Label:
            text: "Some Text"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
        InnerBox:
```

What I want to do now is to use the 'on_text' event of the spinner inside the 'InnerBox' layout to call a function from the associated .py file. I'm not sure if this is the best way but in terms of reusability, I want to use the concept of dynamic classes for certain combinations of widgets.

Julz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Note: kv file - Assigning a value to `id`

When assigning a value to `id`, remember that the ***value isn’t a string***. There are no quotes:

good -> `id: user_selection_label` or `id: user_selection_spinner`

bad -> `id: 'user_selection_label'` or `id: 'user_selection_spinner'`

## Using `on_text` in `class InnerBox()`

### 1) kv file - Dynamic class rule, UserSelectionInput

- Create a new property associated with the `text` property of the `Spinner`

#### Snippets

```
<UserSelectionInput@BoxLayout>:
    text: user_selection_spinner.text

    ...
    Spinner:
        id: user_selection_spinner
        text: 'Select'
        values: root.sp_values
```

### 2) kv file - Dynamic class rule, InnerBox

- Use the `on_text` property event

#### Snippets

```
<InnerBox@AnchorLayout>:
    ...

    BoxLayout:
        ...

        UserSelectionInput:
            on_text:
                print("UserSelectionInput.spinner_1: text=", self.text)

        UserSelectionInput:
            on_text:
                print("UserSelectionInput.spinner_2: text=", self.text)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder


runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
<UserSelectionInput@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size_hint: None, 1
    spacing: 4

    lb_text: ''
    sp_values: '', ''
    text: user_selection_spinner.text

    Label:
        id: user_selection_label
        size_hint_x: 0.4
        text: root.lb_text
    Spinner:
        id: user_selection_spinner
        text: 'Select'
        values: root.sp_values

<InnerBox@AnchorLayout>:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'center'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: None, 1
        width: 2 * root.width / 3
        spacing: 1

        UserSelectionInput:
            width: root.width / 3
            sp_values: 'A', 'B', 'C'
            lb_text: 'Type'
            on_text:
                print("UserSelectionInput.spinner_1: text=", self.text)

        UserSelectionInput:
            width: root.width / 3
            sp_values: 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'
            lb_text: 'Version'
            on_text:
                print("UserSelectionInput.spinner_2: text=", self.text)

<MainContent@GridLayout>:
    rows: 3

    Label:
        text: "Some Text"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        InnerBox:

MainContent:

"""))
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I messed something up when putting my example together - I've checked my code and I never used strings as ids, just here...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inheriting from `BoxLayout` and `AnchorLayout` directly you can instead inherit from their subclasses declared with python code together with functions you want to provide:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<MyNewWidget@MyBoxLayout>:
    Button:
        text: "test"
        on_press: root.my_function()

<MainWidget>:
    MyNewWidget
""")


class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def my_function(self):
        print("MyBoxLayout")


class MainWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```